# VSE won't decode full video width unless it's divisible by 8

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

It seems that my Blender reads/decodes videos in widths that are multiples of 8 – and any remaining pixels are left out. Is there a setting for this? A way to change it to multiples of 2?

I'm running Blender 2.76b on Windows 7 and I recently started using it, so far only as a video editor.

What happens when I for example import and preview an 854×480 MP4 is that only the leftmost 848×480 pixels are shown in the Video Sequence Editor. The rightmost 6×480 are invisible in the preview and they will be black when the video is rendered.

I've tested using a number of H.264 and H.263 MP4 and AVIs encoded with avc1, x264, Xvid. And the same thing happens with an 852×480 DivX: the video width is shown in multiples of 8 and the remaining pixels are left out.

HOWEVER, when using Uncompressed AVI, the entire 854×480 is previewed and can be perfectly rendered to an 854×480 H.264 AVI. (When importing the rendered H.264 back into Blender, though, I will only see 848×480 pixels.)

It seems that only the width is restricted as I can successfully preview a video with a height of 478 pixels (not a multiple of 16, 8 or 4).

I hope this is a silly newbie question with a simple answer...

Comment: That's probably no Blender related question but about Video Encoding Formats? It's usual for encoding in small file sizes to use blocks by 8x8 pixels (like in JPG)... But have you already played around with *Image Crop* or *Image Offset*?

Comment: Well, I don't know if it's an issue within Blender or with an external decoder. But this issue doesn't occur with the same videos in other programs such as MPC-HC or Virtualdub. Only Blender seems to be reading them in widths of 8.

Playing around with Crop and Offset doesn't solve it. With Image Offset the image can be moved further to the left, but the rightmost pixels remain invisible. And Image Crop... well, I guess it only crops out pixels?

Comment: The only workaround (I tried it once but I don't want to do it again) is to pillarbox the videos in Virtualdub: By re-encoding a 854×480 video and adding black pixels to make it 856 pixels wide (a multiple of 8!) I can get Blender to read the full width, and I can then use Crop and Offset to make a render in 854×480.

(And yes, the same thing happens with other widths. With a 716 pixels wide video Blender previews and renders 712 pixels and the remaining 4 are left out.)